# How can I remove blank space between a word and a period in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and i'm looking to remove the blank space between the input word college and the period.  Thanks in advance.

```
print ('I live', miles, 'miles away from', college,'.')
```

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: The comma (`,`) on the `print` automatically adds spaces.